# success function on ajax after validation with laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I made the validation of a form with laravel through ajax. sending data and validation work properly, but when the answer in the js code is received, the success function is never executed; if there are errors in the validation error function is executed and if there are no errors in the validation function also enters the error.
On error, it returns status laravel: 422 and if no errors, returns laravel status: 200.

Thank you for the help that you may be able to provide :)

js:

```
function send(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({


        type: 'post',
        url: userAjax,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
            _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#nameError").fadeOut();

        },
        success: function(errors){

            $('#Register').modal('hide');

        },
        error: function(errors) {


            console.log(errors);

        }

    });

}
```

laravel:
UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function NewUser(UserRequest $request)
    {
        // laravel will validate request itself automatically and
        // will go on if validate pass or will return back with
        // status code 422, input and errors otherwise

        CreateNewUser($request);

    }

    Protected function CreateNewUser(Request $request){

    }


}
```

UserRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
        public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
//            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
//            'password' => 'required|min:8|same:cpassword',
//            'cpassword'=> 'required|min:8',
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have errors in your code.

```
CreateNewUser($request);
```

Needs to be

```
$this->CreateNewUser($request);
```

And

```
Protected function CreateNewUser(Request $request){
```

needs to be:

```
protected function CreateNewUser(Request $request){
```

Comment: hi @Ohgodwhy, Thank you for correcting that mistake, but the function Create new user runs after validation. I corrected and did the test, but still entering the mistake ajax function.